# Retries until they pass or not pass possible with each()

Tags: cypress

I have a page with a grid view and the possibility to filter on elements. If i ex. do the following the test will fail as the grid view hasn´t updated when filter is applied.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="elements"]').each((element)=> {
expect(element.text()).to.equal('something)
});
```

Currently i have a custom command that wait for a loading indicator to disappear but i would love to see if there is a better solution like you can do when you have a single element: `cy.get('[data-cy="elements"]').should('have.text, 'something');`

I´ve seen that you could do something like this but then i have to check each element using eq which isn´t that beautiful:

```
 cy.get('[data-cy="elements"]').should((elements)=> {
    expect(elements.eq(0).text()).to.equal('something');
    expect(elements.eq(1).text()).to.equal('something');
    expect(elements.eq(2).text()).to.equal('something');
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="elements"]').should((elements)=> {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        expect(elements.eq(i).text()).to.equal('something');
    }
}
```

`each` is not suitable here because as the docu ( https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Assertions ) also states, it is not repeatable. So it will fail on the first failing assertion.

So use `should` with a callback function to take advantage of the repeat feature of cypress.